# Merge array with previous value (under defined conditions)

Tags: sql, group-by, count, google-bigquery

Here's the initial table's structure :

```
yearquarter,user_id,gender,generation,country,group_id
2019-03,zfuzhfuzh,M,Y,FR,Group_1
2019-04,zfuzhfuzh,M,Y,FR,Group_1
2020-04,zfuzhfuzh,M,Y,FR,Group_1
2019-03,ggezegz,F,Y,FR,Group_2
2019-04,ggezegz,F,Y,FR,Group_2
2020-04,ggezegz,F,X,FR,Group_2
....
```

I want to be able to know the cumulative amount of user_id quarter after quarter grouped by gender, generation and country. Expected result: for a given combination of gender,generation,country I need the cumulated number of users quarter after quarter.

I started with this :

```
SELECT yearquarter,gender,generation,country,array_agg(distinct user_id IGNORE NULLS) as users FROM my table
WHERE group_id= "mygroup"
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

But I don't know how to go from this to the result I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to count the number of users per gender, generation country and period, and then make a window sum over the periods;

```
select
    gender,
    generation,
    country,
    yearquarter,
    sum(count(distinct user_id)) over(partition by gender, generation, country order by yearquarter) cnt
from mytable
where group_id = 'mygroup'
group by gender, generation, country, yearquarter
order by gender, generation, country, yearquarter
```

I am unsure that bigquery supports `distinct` in window functions. If it doesn't, then we can use a subquery:

```
select
    gender,
    generation,
    country,
    yearquarter,
    sum(count(*)) over(partition by gender, generation, country order by yearquarter) cnt
from (
    select distinct gender, generation, country, yearquarter, user_id
    from mytable
    where group_id = 'mygroup'
) t
group by gender, generation, country, yearquarter
order by gender, generation, country, yearquarter
```

If you want each user to be counted only once, for their first appearance period:

```
select select
    gender,
    generation,
    country,
    yearquarter,
    sum(count(*)) over(partition by gender, generation, country order by yearquarter) cnt
from (
    select gender, generation, country, user_id, min(yearquarter) yearquarter
    from mytable
    where group_id = 'mygroup'
    group by gender, generation, country, user_id
) t
group by gender, generation, country
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. The first query only gives one line and the second always return the index of the quarter (for the cnt column).

I think it can't be a sum of count as a user that belong to the quarter Q but doesn't belong to the Q+1 still need to be counted in the cumulative for Q+1.

Comment: @justberare: I just modified the second query.

Comment: Thanks again!! The results looks much better but when I sum all countries for the last quarter it is bigger than my total distinct users on the entire table (and logically it shouldn't be I guess) :

select distinct gender, generation, country,  user_id
    from  `cleanfox-production.databusiness.optimizeddomainusers`

Comment: @justberare: that's what happens when a user appears in more than one quarter. How would you like to handle this?

Comment: If a user happens once (let's say at quarter Q), it is added to the cumulated number of users for every following quarter. But if it reappears in Q+4 it doesn't get counted twice (it's already in)

Comment: @justberare: ok... see the 3rd query in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL - built purely on top of your initial query with ARRAY_AGG replaced with STRING_AGG

```
#standardSQL
SELECT yearquarter, gender, generation, country, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(cumulative_users)) AS id) AS cumulative_number_of_users
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    STRING_AGG(users) OVER(PARTITION BY gender, generation, country ORDER BY yearquarter) AS cumulative_users
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      yearquarter, gender, generation, country, 
      STRING_AGG(DISTINCT user_id) AS users 
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    WHERE group_id= "mygroup"
    GROUP BY yearquarter, gender, generation, country
  )
) 
-- ORDER BY yearquarter, gender, generation, country
```